# Expand/Collapse set height divs with same class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery div content partial hide, show all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590118/jquery-div-content-partial-hide-show-all)

I know this has been done and I have seen in peoples websites but I can't find it. So I am here.

I need to set up or list multiple divs (4 or 5) on a page with the same class and set each div about 50 pixels tall.  I need them to expand to the div to the full height of the content. Assuming using show/hide or slideUp/slideDown. And when the collapse happens, collapse the div back down to the 50 pixels.  Again I want multiple divs with the same class and fire independently from each other.

Anybody seen this before. I saw [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/2PSME/) but was not quite what I need. I need an expand and close, as well as, all divs need to start out the same height then once the expand is clicked, that specific div needs to expand. Each can be open independent of each other.

Any ideas?

Comment: And can you post HTML + CSS and what you have done so far on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Carlos, I voted to close this. I'm assuming I have answered the question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590118/jquery-div-content-partial-hide-show-all/7590517

Answer (score 1):

If you've got HTML structured like this:

```
<div class='expandable'>
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div class='expandable'>
    <p>Some more content</p>
</div>
```

You can make that work with a bit of joint jQuery and CSS.

First, this CSS would force each `.expandable` to have a minimum height of `50px`:

```
.expandable { min-height:50px; }
```

Then to take care of the expanding/collapsing, you can do something like:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.expandable').bind('click', function () {
        $(this).children().toggle();
    });

});
```

This would hide/show the `.expandable` `DIV`'s content everytime it is clicked. When the content is hidden, the CSS above would prevent the DIV from collapsing on itself smaller than `50px`.

This would allow your `.expandable` to "expand" to it's content's true height when the content is shown as well. Take note that the content has to be in HTML DOM elements for this to work (predictably).

```
<!-- This should work -->
<div class='expandable'>
    <p>foo</p>
</div>

<!-- This probably won't -->
<div class='expandable'>
    bar
</div>
```

Comment: thanks will give this a try.  I know it seems like a mediocre question I asked but I couldn't find a definite answer around.  Thanks.

Comment: No question "too stupid" to ask (outside of trolling, I guess). :D

Comment: This solution doesn't do each one separately. It triggers all of them. Would I use the .each() method?

Comment: What you're saying should only happen if you've got nested `DIV`s that have the same functionality. Update your question with your HTML so that we have a clearer idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

css class:

```
.toggledivs {height:50px;}
.max {height:150px;}
```

Then toggle the classes

```
$('.toggledivs').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('max');
});
```

In that case they are all independent of each other. The initial HTML should be set up like

```
<div class="toggledivs">foo</div><div class="toggledivs">foo</div>
```

If you want to have like the first container (or any of em) add class 'max' to the element lika:

```
<div class="toggledivs max">foo</div><div class="toggledivs">foo</div>
```

Comment: ... or you can just define `.toggledivs { height:50px; }` and get rid of the `.min` class along with the corresponding `.toggleClass('min')` altogether.

Comment: Err yeah, makes more sense :>