# jQuery div content partial hide, show all

Tags: jquery

I have [this solution](http://spoonfedproject.com/jquery/jquery-slide-with-minimum-height/) I am trying to use but it uses ID's.  I want multiple divs on the same page using the same classes.  I changed the ID references to classes but I can not get them to fire independently of each other. They all fire at the same time. How would I get them to fire **independently**. I thought by wrapping the function in a .each() that would fix it but it seems to still be firing all my divs to open at the same time.

Any suggestions are very helpful. Thanks.

```
$(function(){

var slideHeight = 75; // px
var defHeight = $('.wrap').height();
    if(defHeight >= slideHeight){
        $('.wrap').css('height' , slideHeight + 'px');
        $('.read-more').append('<a href="#">Click to Read More</a>');
        $('.read-more a').click(function(){
            var curHeight = $('.wrap').height();
            if(curHeight == slideHeight){
                $('.wrap').animate({
                  height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $('.read-more a').html('Close');
                $('.gradient').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $('.wrap').animate({
                  height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $('.read-more a').html('Click to Read More');
                $('.gradient').fadeIn();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }// end if
```

});

my HTML

`<div class="container">`

`<h1>jQuery slide with minimum height</h1>`

```
<h2>About Billabong</h2>

<div class="wrap">

    <div>

        <p>Gordon Merchant founded Billabong in Burleigh Heads on the Gold Coast in 1973. Combining his passion for surfing with hard work, Gordon designed boardshorts, manufacturing them on the kitchen table and selling through local surf shops and markets.</p>

        <p>Gordon developed his own stitching technique, which made the garments more durable, cost effective and less labor intensive. He employed machinists, moved the operation into a factory, set up a distribution network and sponsored a team of renowned Australian surfers. The business thrived.</p>

        <p>Since those beginnings, Billabong has expanded its product range to include boardsport products such as wetsuits, watches, surfboards, snowboard outerwear and skateboarding apparel.</p>

        <p>Information courtesy of <a title="Billabong" href="http://www.billabong.com/us/">Billabong</a>.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="gradient"></div>

</div>

<div class="read-more"></div>
```

`<div class="container">`

```
<h1>jQuery slide with minimum height Content 2</h1>

<h2>About Billabong</h2>

<div class="wrap">

    <div>

        <p>Gordon Merchant founded Billabong in Burleigh Heads on the Gold Coast in 1973. Combining his passion for surfing with hard work, Gordon designed boardshorts, manufacturing them on the kitchen table and selling through local surf shops and markets.</p>

        <p>Gordon developed his own stitching technique, which made the garments more durable, cost effective and less labor intensive. He employed machinists, moved the operation into a factory, set up a distribution network and sponsored a team of renowned Australian surfers. The business thrived.</p>

        <p>Since those beginnings, Billabong has expanded its product range to include boardsport products such as wetsuits, watches, surfboards, snowboard outerwear and skateboarding apparel.</p>

        <p>Information courtesy of <a title="Billabong" href="http://www.billabong.com/us/">Billabong</a>.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="gradient"></div>

</div>
<div class="read-more"></div>
```

`</div>`

Comment: Can you include your edited jQuery code?  It would make it easier to identify the issue.

Comment: Yes I will. Very simply just changed the # to . pretty much.

Comment: See my answer, make sure you also pay attention to the css, you will need to update the rules from ID to ClassName based

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use all classes and replace your code with this. I hope it is self explanatory why it works.

```
var slideHeight = 75;
$(".container").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrap = $this.children(".wrap");
    var defHeight = $wrap.height();
    if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
        var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
        $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
        $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Click to Read More</a>");
        $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function(event) {
            var curHeight = $wrap.height();
            if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).text("Close");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
            } else {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).text("Click to Read More");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

[Or see a live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/g8c8A/6/)

Comment: Man, I don't know how to thank you enough.  Basically everything got changed to variables, wrapped the .each around it and called it good. Is that right?  I think I going to make a blog post on this and credit you of course. This may help others.

Comment: just a note, you should probably use `.children()` over `.find()`, not only to be more accurate, but it's faster traversing. I'll update my answer and the fiddle.

Comment: Defining elements as variables is a good practice if you plan on using them more than once within the same function/script. It takes time to traverse the DOM and look up these elements, so once you have; store it. ***Local Variables are your friend.*** you will see I'm looping through the containers and within each iteration i'm searching for each applicable elements by their className which are children of the container (instead of grabbing all of the elements with said className). I hope thats a bit more clear.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense. I appreciate the explanation, the pointers and the help.

Comment: @rlemon Its a nice code. It is working fine online. but when i downloaded it and tried to run. it is not performing the functionality. Do you have any idea why is that. I have added Jquery too. still problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use ":first" selector, then remove the class from that object, then call again.  Or if you don't want to remove a class, add a class and use the ":first" and ":not" selectors

Comment: How would you use this in my example I am trying to do.