# jQuery Show/Hide divs one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have slightly modified the code in this post [jQuery div content partial hide, show all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590118/jquery-div-content-partial-hide-show-all/18255709#18255709) to show/hide a list of div's on my page.

I am still learning jQuery and am trying to figure out how I can modify the code so that when I open one div, it will close any other's that are open.

Thanks a lot for any help.  Here is my code block:

```
    function setScroll(){
    var slideHeight = 80;
    $(".container").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrap = $this.children(".wrap");
    var defHeight = $wrap.height();
    if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
        var $readMore = $this.find(".heading");
        $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
        $readMore.append("<div id='clickButton' class='expand-div'>Click for More Info</div>");
         $readMore.children("#clickButton").bind("click", function(event) {    
            var curHeight = $wrap.height();      
            if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: defHeight
                }, "normal");                
                $(this).removeClass("expand-div").addClass("collapse-div");
                $(this).text("Close");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();          
            } else {
                $wrap.animate({
                    height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $(this).removeClass("collapse-div").addClass("expand-div");
                $(this).text("Click for More Info");
                $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Can you upload it to jsfiddle.net so we can also test the full code?

Comment: what have you tried to do? @RoseannSolano here: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/g8c8A/6/

Comment: I am trying to implement what @Farhan suggests below but I can't figure out the exact syntax.  I need to loop through all the divs that are present and collapse them, but I can't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFR6Q/)) demonstrates closing all and opening one.

```
var divs = $('div.highlander').hide();
var which = divs.length;
$('#cycler').click(function () {
    which += 1;
    if (which >= divs.length) {
        which = 0;
    }
    divs.hide();
    divs.eq(which).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Roy's answer is good. I have another example of something you could do. A little bit more general and possible easier to understand. http://jsfiddle.net/sFR6Q/2/

```
    <button class="show1">show1</button>
    <button class="show2">show2</button>
    <button class="show3">show3</button>
    <button class="show4">show4</button>
    <div class="show1">1</div>
    <div class="show2">2</div>
    <div class="show3">3</div>
    <div class="show4">4</div>

     var divs = $("div")
     $('button').click(function () {
         divs.hide();
         $("div." +  $(this).attr("class")).show();
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

First close all the div's irrespective of  if they are open or closed.
Then just open the div you need.

Comment: That's what I'd like to do - but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to do so.  I'm a noob to jQuery (and still learning a lot about javascript) so I was hoping for a little help from the forum.