# Angular read-more button hiding (not truncating) div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a div on which I have a directive that binds HTML content and compile it (sort of `ng-bing-html` directive, but that also compile html to allow insertion of custom directives). The HTML code looks like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="text in texts">
     <div class="content-display" 
          bind-html-compile="text | filterThatOutputsHTMLCodeWithCustomDirectives | nl2br">
     </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I need to display only a restricted portion of each of the `content-display` divs, and have a "read more..." button that would expand the corresponding div to its full size. But I **CANNOT** truncate the text bound in the div, since it's not only text, but can contain HTML tags/directives.

**I found this JQuery code, that accomplish what I want visually** : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590517/2459955 (JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/g8c8A/6/ )

**The problem** is that it's not Angular-compliant, and is pure JQuery. And since my div in which I bind the HTML content is inside an `ng-repeat`... this solution wouldn't work when the `texts` array gets refreshed asynchronously.

Do you see a way to have the same behavior as in the answer linked earlier, but being more "Angular compliant" and applying it automatically to each of the `content-display` divs added by the `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: Didn't try it myself, but have you seen: https://gist.github.com/mrzmyr/706d5322d91956308bd8 ?

Comment: It truncates the text... so it won't work because I have HTML inside the div, not only text. So I _can not_ truncate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up using the approach given in this answer with a slight modification : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590517/2459955

Indeed, since I have a `ng-repeat` adding more divs into the DOM, the `$elem.each()` function wouldn't trigger for these additional divs. The solution is to use a JQuery plugin called [jquery.initialize](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize).

This plugin gives an `$elem.initialize()` function that has exactly the same syntax as `$elem.each()` but initialize() will call the callback again on new items matching the provided selector automatically when they will be added to the DOM. It uses **MutationObserver**.

The final code looks like this. I have some JQuery code in my `module.run()` entry (run once at module initialization):

```
var slideHeight = 400;
$(".content-collapse").initialize(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $wrap = $this.children(".content-display");
  var defHeight = $wrap.height();
  if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
    var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
    var $gradientContainer = $this.find(".gradient-container");
    $gradientContainer.append('<div class="gradient"></div>');
    $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
    $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Read more</a>");
    $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function(event) {
      var curHeight = $wrap.height();
      if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
        $wrap.animate({
          height: defHeight
        }, "normal");
        $(this).text("Read less");
        $gradientContainer.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
      } else {
        $wrap.animate({
          height: slideHeight
        }, "normal");
        $(this).text("Read more");
        $gradientContainer.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

And the corresponding HTML (cleaned for demonstration purpose):

```
 <div class="content-collapse" ng-repeat="text in texts">
    <div class="content-display" bind-html-compile="::text"></div>
    <div class="gradient-container"></div>
    <div class="read-more"></div>
 </div>
```

This solution allows for smooth expand/collapse animation that works fine without any CSS hack, it adds the "Read more" button only on answers that exceeds the desired size limit, and works even if the `texts` array is modified by asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a CSS approach like the one described here: https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar-box {
  max-height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar-box .read-more { 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0; padding: 30px 0; 

  /* "transparent" only works here because == rgba(0,0,0,0) */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black);
}
```

Rather than use jQuery for the read more "reveal", you could create an AngularJS directive for the read more button.

**Directive (untested):**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('readMore', readMoreDirective);

function readMoreDirective() {
    return function(scope, iElement) {
        scope.$on('click', function() {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var parentElement = iElement.parent();
            var grandparentElement = parentElement.parent();
            var parentSiblings = grandparentElement.find("p:not('.read-more')");

            // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights
            // of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
            angular.forEach(parentSiblings, function(ps) {
                totalHeight += ps.outerHeight();
            });

            grandparentElement.css({
                // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
                height: grandparentElement.height(),
                'max-height': 9999
            })
            .animate({
                height: totalHeight
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot the part of the article named "The Reveal with JQuery" where it says it uses JQuery to do the "expand" animation ! It's not only CSS. And the problem would then be exactly the same as with the answer I linked in my question : when more divs are added by the ng-repeat, the JQuery binding won't be added.

Comment: I found this solution that might be a workaround to the click event not being binded to newly inserted DOM elements : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18876600/2459955

Comment: Sorry, was trying to answer on my iPhone but copy/pasting code is a nightmare. I will update to show how the read more button can be done in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

One clean way would be using a class for truncated div, and remove it to display all the text :

**Angular scope :**

```
$scope.truncated = []; // make new array containing the state of the div (truncated or not)
for(var i; i < texts.length -1; i++){
    $scope.truncated.push(0); // fill it with 0 (false by default)
}
$scope.textTruncate = function(index) {
    $scope.truncated[index] = !$scope.truncated[index]; // toggle this value
}
```

**Angular view :**

```
<div ng-repeat="text in texts" ng-class="{truncated: truncated[$index]}">
    <div class="content-display" 
          bind-html-compile="text | filterThatOutputsHTMLCodeWithCustomDirectives | nl2br">
     </div>
    <button ng-click="textTruncate($index)" >Read more</button>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.content-display {
    max-height: 1000px; /* should be your max text height */
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
}
.truncated .content-display {
    max-height: 100px; /* or whatever max height you need */

}
```

*That is what comes in my mind, not sure if it's the most efficient way.*

Comment: This answer seems even easier than @shaun-scovil 's one and would work even if content is not inside <p> tags (which is not desired). Would it be easy to add an animation between the two different sizes with ng-animate ? I never used it.

Comment: Actually, as it uses CSS classes, CSS transitions would do the job easily div .content-display (transition: max-height .3s ease).

Comment: Your solution is working fine. I just think you misplaced the "ng-class", it should be on the content-display div. But I didn't manage to make the transition work. Adding the transition CSS property to the ".content-display" class has no effect. Also, would it be easy to add a fade effect at the bottom of the truncated div ? (as seen on the example I linked in my question)

Comment: Adding an arbitraty "max-height" to the .content-display class allows the transition to be seen. But we should calculate the correct max-height, otherwise the transition-timing (and easing) is wrong.

Comment: Edited my answer with transition. I prefer to put that kind of classes on the container itself (e.g. an article - .content-display's parent instead of .content-display itself). Why ? If I need more styling, I could go all the way with .truncated .children (more reliable than .truncated + button + span, for example).

Comment: Adding a max-height to .content-display works but as I cannot evaluate (at all) the height that the div would be once expanded, if it's 300px the animation would last only 1/3 of the time it would last if height is 1000px once expanded. It works, but it's not very coherent amongst different content sizes.

Comment: As it's not the question here, I won't post more about transition. But you will find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860631/how-to-get-same-effect-as-jquerys-slidetoggle-using-css-3-transitions (to sum up : replace max-height with height: 100px / height: auto).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<p data-dd-collapse-text="100">{{veryLongText}}</p>` inside the **ng-repeat**

**Documentation** [Here](https://github.com/doukasd/AngularJS-Components)

Comment: It won't work, because it creates two separate spans with truncated text inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I had o implement this for a data table. I found following directive and it worked smoothly as per requirements:-

Ui Framework- Angular js

In Html

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="proj in errors">
        <td dd-text-collapse dd-text-collapse-max-length="40" 
        dd-text-collapse-text="{{proj.description}}"></td>
```

in Javascript:-

```
    app.directive('ddTextCollapse', ['$compile', function($compile) {


      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: true,
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


              /* start collapsed */
              scope.collapsed = false;


              /* create the function to toggle the collapse */
              scope.toggle = function() {
                  scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
              };


              /* wait for changes on the text */
              attrs.$observe('ddTextCollapseText', function(text) {


                  /* get the length from the attributes */
                  var maxLength = scope.$eval(attrs.ddTextCollapseMaxLength);


                  if (text.length > maxLength) {
                      /* split the text in two parts, the first always showing */
                      var firstPart = String(text).substring(0, maxLength);
                      var secondPart = String(text).substring(maxLength, text.length);


                      /* create some new html elements to hold the separate info */
                      var firstSpan = $compile('<span>' + firstPart + '</span>')(scope);
                      var secondSpan = $compile('<span ng-if="collapsed">' + secondPart + '</span>')(scope);
                      var moreIndicatorSpan = $compile('<a ng-if="!collapsed">... </a>')(scope);
                      var lineBreak = $compile('<br ng-if="collapsed">')(scope);
                      var toggleButton = $compile('<a class="collapse-text-toggle" ng-click="toggle()">{{collapsed ? "(less)" : "(more)"}}</a>')(scope);


                      /* remove the current contents of the element
                       and add the new ones we created */
                      element.empty();
                      element.append(firstSpan);
                      element.append(secondSpan);
                      element.append(moreIndicatorSpan);
                      element.append(lineBreak);
                      element.append(toggleButton);
                  }
                  else {
                      element.empty();
                      element.append(text);
                  }
              });
          }
      };
       }]);
```